# What does "fottitura" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

While reading Gianrico Carofiglio's book,"Né qui né altrove", I came across the word "fottitura" whose definition I can't find.
"Un sacco di miei clienti avevano comprato gli appartamenti e si sono ritrovati questa bella  **fottitura** senza nessuna colpa."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a very colloquial and vulgar term, from *fottere*, which apart from its literal sense of “to fuck” is often used for “to swindle”. So a *fottitura* is a swindle, a rip-off. In the same figurative sense, the colloquial word *fregatura* (from *fregare*) is more widely used.